# Title section with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

using the TikZ package to create a style for book sections like the image below?

[image]

Comment: Looks similar to the goals of [Gradient fill around section headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173699/gradient-fill-around-section-headings). The TikZ code would be different, obviously, but the basic structure should be identical.

Answer (score 14):

I believe I got a somewhat more organized.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.5in,bmargin=1in,tmargin=1in,centering]{geometry}

\definecolor{cor1}{HTML}{57C3CF}
\definecolor{cor2}{HTML}{4EA8B1}


\newcommand\SecTitle[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (A) [rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=1cm,color=white,fill=cor2, text width=\textwidth-3cm,align=left] {\hspace{1.5cm}\parbox{\textwidth}{\huge\textbf{\textsf{#4}}}};
    \fill[fill=cor1] (A.north west) -- ($(A.north west)+(1.5cm,0)$) -- ($0.5*(A.north west)-0.5*(A.north west)-(0.5*\textwidth-2.5cm,0)$)--($(A.south west)+(1.5cm,0)$)--(A.south west);
    \node [color=white](A.north west) at ($0.5*(A.north west)-0.5*(A.north west)-(0.5*\textwidth-1cm,0)$) {\Huge\textbf{\textsf{\thesection}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\SecTitle{east}{west}{0\paperwidth}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Teste}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Two}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\section{Test Section Three}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test Section Four}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]