# Bar behind section title spanning the width of the page

Tags: titles, titlesec, mdframed

Is there a way I can use the `titlesec` package or the `mdframed` package to produce a section heading like the following:

[image]

Here, the section title box begins at the left margin.

As a followup question, is there a way to draw this box so that the box spans the ENTIRE width of the page (literally)? Also, is there a general way to create section heading styles using `mdframed`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would use the more powerful `tcolorbox` for this.

Comment: A starting point could be this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173699/gradient-fill-around-section-headings