# How to add symbol/rule/tikz drawing at the end of the section on the same line, and keep default spacing

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I'd like to add symbols/rules/tikz drawing at the end of a title to obtain something like:

[image]

or

[image]

I tried to define something like:

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\xrfill[1pt]{8pt}[secondaryColor]}\\]
```

(the `{}` seems to be necessary or it wont compile), but the spacing and indentation is wrong after the section:

[image]

the proper indentation and spacing being:

[image]

what is the proper way to get a proper spacing with `\titlesec`?

**MWE:** Note that for the tikz drawing, I've no idea if it's the best way to proceed (I use 3 tikz pictures, 2 with `remember picture` spaced with `hfill`, and one `overlay` in charge of the drawing), but I can't find any better way to get the position of the start/end of the current line. Let me know if you know one.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mytikzDrawing}{%
  % Ugly trick to find start/end of line... happy to hear better solutions.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (startPosition) {\phantom{X}};
  \end{tikzpicture}\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (endPosition) {\phantom{X}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % \node[fill=blue!50,minimum width=\linewidth,minimum height=3mm] {AAA};
    \fill[left color=red!30, right color=yellow!30] (startPosition.north west) -- (endPosition.north east) -- (endPosition.south east) -- (startPosition.south west) -- cycle;
    \draw[decorate,decoration=snake,draw=blue!50] (startPosition.east) -- (endPosition.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xhfill} % To draw color \hrulefill https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155960/

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{secondaryColor}{RGB}{255,236,209}

\usepackage{titlesec}
%% Bad spacing after:
%\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\xrfill[1pt]{8pt}[secondaryColor]}\\]
% or with the tikz version:
% \titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\ \mytikzDrawing\\]

\begin{document}

Here is what I get when using nothing:

\section{Hello}

I'd prefer to get something like that (the problem being the spacing):\\

\noindent{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 2 \hspace{.3em} A simple version \xrfill[1pt]{8pt}[secondaryColor]}\\

Or something like that:

\noindent{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 3 \hspace{.3em} A complex version \mytikzDrawing{}}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Gradient fill around section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173699/5764)

Comment: @Werner Thanks a lot, it worked great (see my answer)!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Werner's comment pointing to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173699/gradient-fill-around-section-headings), I managed to understand how to do. The idea is to load the option `explicit` in the package, which forces the user to add `#1` where the title is supposed to appear, and to put the tikz code in the pre-text (together with `#1`) instead of in the post-text. That way, the shape `runin` is not needed, and the spacing is directly the expected one:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1\hrulefill}
```

For a complete example with `tikz` using `linegoal` to simplify the process to determining the remaining part of the line (see commented code for colored line):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{linegoal} % \linegoal gives the remaining space on current line
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newlength{\remDim} % Dimension that remains after the section title
\newcommand{\mytikzDrawing}{%
  \setlength\remDim{\linegoal}% Store the remaining dimension to draw a node of the appropriate width
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[minimum width=\remDim,minimum height=7pt,inner sep=0pt,fill,left color=red!30, right color=yellow!30] (mainbox) {};
    \draw[decorate,decoration=snake,draw=blue!50] (mainbox.east) -- (mainbox.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{xhfill} % To draw color \hrulefill https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155960/
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{secondaryColor}{RGB}{255,236,209}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%% Rule version:
% \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1\hrulefill}
%% Colored rule version:
% \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1\xrfill[1pt]{8pt}[secondaryColor]}
%% Tikz version:
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1 \mytikzDrawing}

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}

\lipsum[1]

\section{A second section}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```